# DATEPART(ww,Date) with SET DATEFIRST

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I´m using SQL Server 2005

I´m trying to get the week with DatePart(ww,date) function

My code

```
SELECT datepart(ww,'2012-01-08 00:00:00')
```

**Return 2**

But I want ...

**Return 1**

According with IS0-8601 and this table from this [website](http://espanol.epochconverter.com/fecha-y-hora/numero-de-semanas.php?ano=2012)

YEAR 2012
Week-01  From 2012-1-2 to   2012-1-8 
...

Am I wrong?

There is any trick with SET DATEFIRST 1, I´m trying without success.

Thanks for your time

I can´t use ISO_WEEK, because SQL Server 2005 don´t work

[image]

Comment: Use `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,` and [please stop using lazy shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx). Also `DATEFIRST` has to do with days of the week, not weeks of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ISO_WEEK`:

```
SELECT datepart(ISO_WEEK,'2012-01-08 00:00:00')
```

You can read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

**Edit:**

I didn't realize `ISO_WEEK` was not available in SQL Server 2005. Since it's based on the Thursday of the week, the problem now shifts to finding the Thursday from the given day:

```
DECLARE @Date date = '2012-01-08'
DECLARE @Thursday date = DATEADD(DAY, 3-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, @Date)

SELECT (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,@Thursday) - 1) / 7 +1
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron Bertrand, Zoff Dino, but ISO_WEEK, dont work with SQL Server 2005, there is another way to do it?

Comment: @yaqui Well, considering you are using software that is 10 years old and out of mainstream support, you could think about upgrading. Short of that, you can implement a function like [Example A in the CREATE FUNCTION docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

Comment: Uh, isn't it only based on Thursday for the year 2012? Will your code identify the right week number for all 7 days in the first ISO week of 2010, 2011, 2013, 2014, etc.?

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand. The new code now works correctly across all years.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Thanks, Yes, I have to work with olds records from 2012,2013 and 2014, but I´m working year to year, so the function above works for me. Thank you very much!!!